# Link TransformBlock producing IEnumerable<T> to block that receives T

Tags: c#, asynchronous, parallel-processing, tpl-dataflow

I'm writing a web-gallery **scraper** and I want to parallel the processing for files as much as possible with TPL Dataflow.

To scrape, I first get the gallery main page and parse the HTML to get the image page links as a list. Then I go to each page in the list and parse the HTML to get the link to the image which I then want to save to disk.

Here's the outline of my program:

```
var galleryBlock = new TransformBlock<Uri, IEnumerable<Uri>>(async uri =>
{
    // 1. Get the page
    // 2. Parse the page to get the urls of each image page
    return imagePageLinks;
});

var imageBlock = new TransformBlock<Uri, Uri>(async uri =>
{
    // 1. Go to the url and fetch the image page html
    // 2. Parse the html to retrieve the image url
    return imageUri;
});

var downloadBlock = ActionBlock<Uri>(async uri =>
{
    // Download the image from uri to list
});

var opts = new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true};
galleryBlock.LinkTo(imageBlock, opts); // this doesn't work, as I'm returning a list and not a single Item. However I want to progress that block in parallel.
imageBlock.LinkTo(downloadBlock, opts);
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: He is wondering how to send individual urls to the action block, however the transformBlock is returning a list so the linkTo isn't working because doesn't want a list

Comment: Simply replace `TransformBlock` with `TransformManyBlock`, if I understand correctly.

Comment: I took the liberty of re-titling your question. I hope it's an appropriate change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `TransformManyBlock` in place of your `TransformBlock`:

```
var galleryBlock = new TransformManyBlock<Uri, Uri>(async uri =>
{
    return Enumerable.Empty<Uri>(); //just to get it compiling
});

var imageBlock = new TransformBlock<Uri, Uri>(async uri =>
{
    return null;  //just to get it compiling
});

var opts = new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true };
galleryBlock.LinkTo(imageBlock, opts); // bingo!
```

Comment: I just had to make dinner, you beat me to it!, upvote, dataflow is awesome

Comment: I (heart) dataflow too. TPL's unsung hero.

Comment: So, if I understood your answer correctly, a `TransformManyBlock` takes 1 item and produces n?

Comment: @Ruhrpottpatriot Correct. Specifically, `TransformManyBlock<TIn,TOut>` takes a delegate that returns an `IEnumerable<TOut>` and offers each `TOut` item in each `IEnumerable<TOut>` individually. It's very similar to LINQs `SelectMany`.

Comment: Hmmm... I always thought of `SelectMany` as a method to flatten lists, i.e. `IEnumerable<TList>` -> `TList`.

Comment: @Ruhrpottpatriot Yes, `SelectMany` takes a delegate (specifically `Func<TIn,IEnumerable<TOut>>`) that takes any single item `TIn` and produces an `IEnumerable<TOut>`. It then offers each item in the `IEnumerable<TOut>`s individually. That single input item for the delegate might itself be `IEnumerable`, which would be the specific list-flattening case that you describe.

Comment: Ah, so I missed many `SelectMany` cases in the past. Nice to know.
One last thing: To control how many `imageBlocks`are running, I have the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`, right?

Comment: @Ruhrpottpatriot Yes, `ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism` will indeed control that. You might also want to look at `BoundedCapacity` which must be at least as large as `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` and controls how many "in-flight"+queued items a block will take from its source. Thereafter it's a one-in one-out policy. A large `BoundedCapacity` will cause the block to greedily consume everything from its source and buffer it in its own queue.